# Support screen issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-screen-support

I added support screen for different sizes for the devices but when i test it it seems that the buttons are a bit up,not like in the preview(I have the same phone as the preview).

Here's the layout for my phone specs:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundapp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/poweroffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/FlashBlinkButton"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blinkoffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/AlarmButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/AlarmButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/AlarmButton"
        android:src="@drawable/alarmoffline"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FlashBlinkButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also have another device where it's like the other one a bit up even when i put the configuration qualifiers .

Comment: Can you provide screenshots to calrify what kind of error you experience?

Comment: @jonas.koeritz alright!

Answer (score 0):

You will never achieve a fool-proof layout with this techique. Try adding the background of the button (the embossed circles) to the ImageButtons instead, they will move together with the buttons and nothing will be off-center.

Comment: that's not the problem...everything works fine except that it always brings the button a bit up

Comment: You will not be able to fix this issue for all screens, unless you change the way your screen gets composed.

Comment: it's something about the dimens.xml in the values...because it affects all types of screen,not just one layout.

Comment: Never try to fit an app to any single phone. Rethink your layout, try to keep it as generic as possible.